# Photoshop zoom settings

Tags: adobe-photoshop, creative-cloud, zoom

Before I formatted my Mac, I'm sure I had Ps set up so that, when I zoomed, it didn't change the size of the window that my document was in.

Now when I zoom in, or zoom out, the window will resize automatically along with it

I'm sure there was a setting to change this in preferences, but have no idea where it is?

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a setting in the preferences:

1. Go to `Photoshop > Preferences` (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>; `Edit > Preferences` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> for Windows);
2. In the `General` tab, untick 'Zoom Resizes Windows';
3. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>.